# connecting external MQTT publisher with NODE-RED

Tags: node.js, iot, mosquitto, node-red

In my current project, I am trying to connect my external temperature sensor  to NODE-RED.

I have plugged MQTT with the external sensor. This sensor is publishing data with `tempMeasurement` topic. The configuration of MQTT publisher is as follows:

```
public class MQTTPublisher {

    // public static final String BROKER_URL =
    // "tcp://broker.mqttdashboard.com:1883";
    public static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883";

    private MqttClient client;

    public MQTTPublisher() {
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, MqttClient.generateClientId(),
                    new MemoryPersistence());
            client.connect();

        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void publish(String topicName, int qos, byte[] payload)
            throws MqttException {
        final MqttTopic topic = client.getTopic(topicName);

        final MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(payload);
        topic.publish(message);

        System.out.println("Published data. Topic: " + topic.getName()
                + "  Message: " + payload);
    }
}
```

On the other side in Node-RED, I have created MQTT node, that has subscribe "tempMesurement". The configuration of MQTT node in NODE-RED is as follows:

[image]

[image]

My problem is that MQTT subscriber node is showing **disconnected** message as show in the above figure. Could you please suggest - what is wrong with the configuration in NODE-RED? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Update the question with a image of the MQTT server configuration dialog (the one shown when you click on the pencil icon). But I think you have put the full url in the server box instead of just 'test.mosquitto.org'

Comment: @hardillb: I have updated the question with configuration. Please note that I have not made any changes in the "Security", "Birth Message", and will message" tab.

Comment: As @hardillb said, you should not include 'tcp://' in the broker server. Remove that and it should connect.

Comment: The problem has been resolved now by removing "tcp://". Can you right this solution as answer. This would help other to see the solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to remove the *tcp://* from the sever name in the config screen